# Create constructor(?) to retrieve object from cache or recreate if null

Tags: c#, caching, webforms

I'm building an intranet using C# webforms. I've got a list object with a bunch of users which I'm cacheing. I'm trying to create a constructor that will do the following when I reference MainADList:

1. if it exists in the cache and is not null, use it
2. else generate the list and cache it

I've got the code to do the caching and retrieving, but it isn't encapsulated nicely in a way that I'd like.

```
public Users MainADList = new Users();

private void GenerateADList()
{
    MainADList = (Users) Cache["MainADList"];

    if (MainADList == null || MainADList.Count == 0)
    {
       //generate the list....

       Cache["MainADList"] = MainADList;
    }
 }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't create a *constructor* which does that. A constructor *always* creates a new object.

Instead, create a static *factory* method:

```
public static Users GetUsers()
{
    // Consult the cache, and create a new instance if necessary.
}
```

This *may* be a [singleton](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx) - but it certainly doesn't have to be. (I wouldn't artificially impose its singleton-ness unless I really had to. I'm not a big fan of the singleton pattern.)

Alternatively, instead of a static factory method, you could have an *instance* method in a factory class:

```
public class UsersFactory
{
    // Construct it with a cache, or whatever's required

    public Users GetUsers()
    {
        // Use the cache, or construct a new value.
    }
}
```

Now this is more testable - because you're not relying on any static (global) state. Instead, you can create a new factory from a new cache in each test.

In *all* of these solutions, you need to consider what threading behaviour you want. If you want to make sure that you only construct the value once, you'll need to use `Lazy<T>`, static initializer guarantees, or locking.

Comment: Singleton: the most easily abused design pattern known to programming

Comment: Right, I've read the same thing about Singletons. What's an alternative in my case?

Comment: Jon, so each time I need my list I'll call GetUsers()? I was hoping there'd be an inherent call to GetUsers() when I reference my object...

Comment: Well if singleton's are bad, then what Jon Skeet proposed would be the right choice,so basically a factory method in the class.

Comment: @user948060: Why would you want to hide the call? See my edit for an alternative to having a static factory method - have a factory class instead.

Comment: @JonSkeet I don't want to hide it so much as not have to explicitly call it each time. What do you think of dasblinkenlight's suggestion below?

Comment: @user948060: Personally that looks messier to me than using a simple method call. (You realize you'd have that code every time you wanted to get at the value?)

Comment: @JonSkeet The rationale to using any paradigm over another is communication. You, as a team, might simply agree that MyClass.Current can be used more recklessly, without taxing the database, whereas MyClass.GetCurrent() may or may not tax the database.

Comment: @JonSkeet There's certainly good rational in "surfacing" hidden method calls. But, I might also be inclined to argue most of your method calls and overhead are hidden anyway.

Comment: @svidgen: I don't see how your comment really applies. I wasn't discussing the benefits of a property vs a method - I was discussing `factory.GetUsers()` vs '((Lazy<Users>) Cache["MainADList"]).Value' - the latter simply looks messier to me.

Comment: @JonSkeet My bad. I think I glossed over a comment or two. +1

Comment: Regarding threading, what's the recommended way? This is an intranet with users from active directory; the directory doesn't change often, and I was thinking to have the object recreated every hour or so.

Comment: Why I am having trouble accessing Cache from my Users class?

Comment: @user948060: Were you using `Page.Cache` before? If so, it makes sense that you can't do that from `Users`. There may be a way of getting at the cache some other way - I'm not sure.

Comment: @user948060: Yup, `HttpContext.Current.Cache` is probably what you want.

Comment: Where did dasblinkenlight's answer go??

Comment: @user948060: I think he deleted it.

Comment: @JonSkeet, I need a bit more help. I'm a bit confused. I like your solution, but I need to take threading into account, and I'm not sure which way to go. Assuming I want to refresh the object every 30 minutes, how/where do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

One general pattern you could follow:

```
public class ClassName {
  public static Object CachedObject {
    get {
      Object o = (Object)Cache['CacheKey'];
      if (o == null)
      {
         o = GetData();
         Cache["CacheKey"] = o;
      }
      return o;
    }
  }
}
```

And treat **ClassName.CachedObject** as though it's always, eternally, and magically populated.

Comment: Note that this implementation of the singleton pattern (which is what this is, but using a cache instead of a field) isn't thread-safe. I dislike singletons due to the lack of testability. I dislike this implementation for its lack of thread safety. See the article linked in my answer for alternative implementations.

Comment: My solution is intended to mirror the OP's question, assuming the `Cache` in question is a stand-in for "some suitable caching mechanism."

Comment: @JonSkeet Though ... it just occurred to me, there is still a locking (or lack of) problem. That said, I think I'll leave the answer as-is. Your answer is plenty sufficient!

Answer (score -3):

What you want is known as a Singleton.

Basically what you should do with the code you already have is something like this:

```
public static GetList
{
   get 
      {
          //check if list exists and create it - so basically call your private constructor
          //return cached list
      }
}
```