# Replacing a constructor call with a factory method call by using a proxy in C#

Tags: c#, factory, proxy-object

I might be going crazy, but I swear I've seen a snippet that allows the consumers of your code to write `new Foo()` while something like `FooProxy.Create()` is called behind the scenes instead of the constructor. I've been searching and searching for it, but now I cannot find it at all. I do not plan to use this at all, since it looks like an antipattern to me, but I want to make sure I didn't dream it all up.

Comment: What's the problem? Why do you think it's an anti-pattern?

Comment: I've never seen `new X` not create an X. The only thing I've heard about that might come close is [MS Fakes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9677445/mock-framework-vs-ms-fakes-frameworks). I'd not use this outside of testing.

Comment: @user28 there are some small exceptions... `new string(new char[0])` will return the `string.Empty` singleton... but they are rare exceptions handled by the CLR.

Comment: Sounds like a [Singleton pattern](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx) to me. But instead of a Property `Instance` for C# you can make a method `Create()` that returns the Instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The response seems to be no.... You have only dreamed. From https://stackoverflow.com/a/14343648/613130:

> Q:Create constructor(?) to retrieve object from cache or recreate if null
>
> A: You can't create a constructor which does that. A constructor always creates a new object.
> Instead, create a static factory method:

Note that it is surely possible to use [Fody](https://github.com/Fody/Fody) (a tool able to modify an assembly post compilation) to create a plugin that replaces direct `new Foo()` to `FooProxy.Create()`